# How to improve OCR results with Google Vision API and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, google-vision

I am working with Google Vision API and Python to apply `text_detection` which is an OCR function of Google Vision API which detects the text on the image and returns it as an output. My original image is the following:

[image]

I have used the following different algorithms:

1) Apply `text_detection` to the original image

2) Enlarge the original image by 3 times and then apply `text_detection`

3) Apply `Canny`, `findContours`, `drawContours` on a mask (with OpenCV) and then `text_detection` to this

4) Enlarge the original image by 3 times, apply `Canny`, `findContours`, `drawContours` on a mask (with `OpenCV`) and then `text_detection` to this

5) Sharpen the original image and then apply `text_detection`

6) Enlarge the original image by 3 times, sharpen the image and then apply `text_detection`

The ones which fare the best are (2) and (5). On the other hand, (3) and (4) are probably the worse among them.

**The major problem is that `text_detection` does not detect in most cases the minus sign especially the one of '-1.00'.** 
Also, I do not know why, sometimes it does not detect '-1.00' itself at all which is quite surprising as it does not have any significant problem with the other numbers.

**What do you suggest me to do to detect accurately the minus sign and in general the numbers?**

(Keep in mind that I want to apply this algorithm to different boxes so the numbers may not be at the same position as in this image)

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same problem. Your end goal is to correctly identify the text. For OCR conversion you are using a third party service or tool (google API / tesseract etc.)

All the the approach that you are talking about become meaningless because whatever transformations that you are doing using openCV will be repeated by tesseract.The best you should do is supply the input in a easy format.

What did work for me the best is breaking the image is parts (BOXES - "SQUARES AND RECTANGLES" - **using a sample code for identifying the rectangles in all channels in openCV repo examples** using https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py) and then crop it and then send it for OCR by parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hmm, interesting remark. However, I feel that the fact that these APIs are applying image processing does not necessarily render any additional images processing meaningless but you have a point. Yes, the idea of sending an image in parts is a quite good idea but then you must resolve in way the problem of noise addition because you won't obviously send the part of the image as it is but enlarged in order to make the job of OCR easier. But yes when I send a really large image of one single large negative number then the minus sign is detected.

Comment: But usually (large) photos do not include a single number which captures the whole image so you must focus on a part of the image, enlarge it and then reduce the noise in it....so again the question of effective noise reduction techniques arises...

Comment: Break in parts and send for tesseract OCR as is. You should get - sign.

Comment: Haha, I like your confidence in Tesseract even though I do not really share it. To start with, I already tested this in GCP Vision API and I did not take any significantly better results but I will give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *Google Vision API which detects the text on the image*, so it is not obvious for a text detection API to detect negative numbers in first place. Assuming that fact that you may not able to re-train the API as per your case, I would recommend you to write a simple script which filters the contours on the basis of it's shape and size, using this script you can easily segment out the negative signs and then merge it with the output from Google Vision API as

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread("path/to/img.jpg", 0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

i, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# filter the contours.
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 5 < cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 50 and float(w)/h > 3:
        print "I have detected a minus sign at : ", x, y, w, h
```

After this filtering process you can make a calculated guess if a given digit has a negative sign close it it's left side.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a good idea and I have already encountered it somewhere on Internet. But to be honest I think that `findContours` will return various contours from an image which you do not expect so I do not think that the size of contours will filter out properly the symbols which do not interest me. Finally, yes, I am thinking about utilising the fact that the minus sign is located always (in my cases) in front of the numbers so I can have an additional condition related to this.

Comment: I have also taken into account the aspect ratio of contour in `float(w)/h > 3` which confirms that the contours has more horizontal component than vertical component by a factor of 3, you can add more attributes depending upon your use cases.

Comment: Yes, cool, nice idea too. But in this sense, perhaps it would be even better to focus directly on the region at the left of the number and see if there is a major colour difference because if there is a minus sign then it will be differently coloured from the background. In this way, I won't mess with contours etc.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Vision API uses Tesseract, which I think it does,,
then optimization is usually as follows:

1. Sharpen
2. Binarize (or grayscale if you must)
3. Trim borders (Tesseract likes smooth background)
4. Deskew (Tesseract tolerates very small skew angle. It likes nice straight text lines)
5. Reshape and resize (Put it in a page-like shape and resize if necessary)

As for negative signs, well, use Tesseract directly, if you can.
You will be able to retrain it or to download better trainings.
Or well, you can correct the errors using additional algorithm. I.e. implement your recheck as suggested in ZdaR's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am pretty sure that GCP Vision API and Tesseract are distinct. Tesseract is considered to be a little bit worse than GCP Vision API so I am not sure that Tesseract will directly detect the minus sign. But yes as I wrote above I was using a combination of these techniques (and the images I was using did not have any skew).

Comment: The combination of (3) and (5) is quite tricky because after this the image probably will have significant noise which will make the detection of the minus sign and of the text in general considerably more difficult .  Finally, yes, training is a good idea but to be honest I expected that in these basic cases no training is required.

Comment: There are always tricks to avoid most of the noise. You just have to know them. E.g. construct a background mask out of some parameters and do the background substraction instead of binarization first. Use contours and those that are filled with a little maximas in colour consider text etc. etc. OCR is not exactly easy to do if professional work is needed.

Comment: As for Tesseract being worse, well, I expected that GV is only better trained Tesseract. It probably even trains itself continuously. Even if it is not really Tesseract, you can expect some algorithms have been pulled from there.

Comment: Yes, for sure you have to know them in order to apply them. Concerning background subtraction,  If I am not wrong this is like trimming borders as you said above. So I am not sure that doing firstly (3) and then (2) instead of (2) and then (3) will significantly improve the results. Concerning contour detection, in the way that you are saying this it seems that we may not even use Google Vision API to to OCR but only `findContours`. But I am not sure that either this or even the combination of Google Vision API with `findContours will produce consistently better results.

Comment: (I may be wrong in some of the things I am saying but I have already tested some things.)

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Border trimming only removes content from sides of an image that it considers useless. Like lines on sides that can appear when scanning a page. Tesseract likes to have them remove (don't ask why, I don't know. Perhaps newer versions do it by themselves.). Background substraction affects whole image. It removes the background from it. It is easy when you have a camera for instance and known background. Then when something appears in view, over that background, you can remove it and see the object only.

Comment: To have a background substraction without known background is tricky. You have to estimate how the background looks like. What I suggested with contours is not an OCR. It is to recognize which parts of your image contain text. And which not. In this way, you can construct a mask to remove images and stuff along with the background. You say which parts will not be touched by the mask. Why this and not cropping? Leave it to OCR to decide what box goes first and what next. Although Gopal's solution is not exactly bad one.

Comment: To clarify more my contour solution. Area with dense colours (points over a trashold or differing much from background) are most certainly images. Areas containing a lot of blank space is most probably text. It is easy to calculate using ratio of number of coloured points/number of blanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even though I disagree with some of your points I will certainly take it into account.